# Чи має запозичений термін “толерантність” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: from-english, синоніми, запозичені-слова, іншомовні-слова

Знайомлячись з нормами сучасного етикету, [зустрів](http://etyket.org.ua/tolerantnist.htm) такий термін як "толерантність". Де його пояснюють як:

> **Толерантність** - це здатність без агресії сприймати думки, поведінку, форми самовираження та спосіб життя іншої людини, які відрізняються від власних.

На Вікіпедії загальновживаного значення [не наводиться](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)).

СУМ-11 надає [пояснення](http://sum.in.ua/s/tolerantnyj):

> **ТОЛЕРА́НТНИЙ**, а, е, книжн. Поблажливий, терпимий до чиїхсь думок, поглядів, вірувань тощо. *Толерантний був [редактор] — для виду (Іван Франко, X, 1954, 115); У мене є один дуже близький друг .., і він мириться якось з моїми виступами.., хоч я виражаюсь перед ним далеко гостріше, ніж тепер перед Вами. Я сподіваюсь, що в сьому Ви будете до мене толерантні? (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 266); — Він.. чоловік толерантний, більше, мабуть, ніж моя Таня... (Володимир Гжицький, Чорне озеро, 1961, 193).*

Офіційний сайт Української мови [пропонує](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/p/poblazhlivij/38-1-0-12378) "толерантний" як:

> Синоніми до слова ПОБЛАЖЛИВИЙ: невимогливий, ліберальний; (до чого) терпимий, *толерантний*; (усміх) доброзичливий; (суд) вибачливий, милостивий.

Отже, чи має термін “толерантний” та похідні від терміну слова, додаткові (крім наведених) відповідні синоніми та/або українські похідники?

Comment: Вважаю, що вам варто уточнити, чим са́ме не підходять варіанти, знайдені самостійно — чому не *«поблажливий»*, не *«терпимий»*? Чи навіть *«добрий»*? Це могло б точніше скерувати можливі відповіді.

Answer (score 2):

Все ж найкращим варіантом буде "терпимий" зідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/tolerantnyj), [Словотвору](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/tolerantnist), [цього](http://promovu.in.ua/adopted-words/) онлайн збірника деяких українських відповідників, [Вікісловника](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) та цього [сайту](https://irynadenysjuk.blogspot.com/2015/01/blog-post_13.html). Згідно до [цього джерела](http://ukrainian.abcthesaurus.com/browse_synonyms/synonyms_for_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96.html) можливими є варіанти: "щедрий", "неупереджений", "доброзичливий". А онлайн [словник24](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) дає ще можливий синонім до цього слова - "здатний витримати". І врешті решт згідно до [цього сайту](https://explain_words_uk.academic.ru/6723/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) ще можна замінити це слово за допомогою слів "поблажливий", "ліберальний", "невимогливий", "лояльний".

Comment: але ж "ліберальний", "лояльний" теж слова іншомовного походження. То чим же краще замінювати одне іншомовне слово іншим? Тільки тим, що одні слова вже давно у вжитку на відміну від інших?

Comment: @Ivan, завжди краще мати вибір, ніж його не мати. Хоча згоден, що в цьому разі автор запитання питає саме про слова українського походження. Але й відповідач у цьому разі як основний варіант наводить саме слово українського походження «терпимий».